# (Python) Convert float to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Amy', 'Chris', 'Sam'], 'date': [1.597104e+12, 1.600906e+12, np.nan]})
print(df)

   name          date
0   Amy  1.597104e+12
1 Chris  1.600906e+12
2   Sam           NaT
```

I checked the types of date which shows float64, then I used `pd.to_datetime` to convert it. But I got the result that is not correct.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df)

    name                     date
0    Amy  1970-01-01 00:26:37.104
1  Chris  1970-01-01 00:26:40.906
2    Sam                      NaT
```

I also tried `df['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['date'], unit='d') + pd.to_datetime('1899-12-30')`, but the result below is still incorrect.

```
    name                           date
0    Amy  2055-09-23 23:20:48.000057344
1  Chris  1839-08-30 13:23:48.304879616
2    Sam                            NaT
```

I really have no clue about fixing this, so can someone assist here?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include what you would like the result to look like.

Comment: Hi @hrokr - I'm pretty new to the stack overflow inner circle, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

That's a Unix time_t value (seconds since 1970-01-01) but in milliseconds.  The first one is 2020-08-11.  Pandas expects floating point time values to be in nanoseconds.  So, this will work:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] * 1000000)
```

As in:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date']*1000000)
0   2020-08-11 00:00:00
1   2020-09-24 00:06:40
2                   NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tim mentioned, your units weren't the default units for [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). And, while his method certainly works, its probably not what you would want for a very large number of conversions since the extra step adds about 8% more computing time. So, this

[image]

vs this

[image]

Both of which give you:

```
    name    date
0   Amy     2020-08-11 00:00:00
1   Chris   2020-09-24 00:06:40
2   Sam     NaT
```